# Node.js Javascript program killed processing 34kb file

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

```
  var parseFile = function(filename, fieldMap) {
      var array = [];
      var f = fs.readFileSync(filename);

      array = f.toString().split('\n');

      array = array.map(splitLines);
      array = array.map(function(lineArray) {
          var out = [];
          fieldMap.forEach(function(value, key) {
              out.push(lineArray[key]);
          });
          return out;
      });

      return array;
  };

  var splitLines = function(line) {
      return line.split('^');
  };

  (function () {
  for (var k in requiredFieldMap) {
      var v = requiredFieldMap[k];
      fs.writeFileSync(k + '.json', JSON.stringify(parseFile(k + '.txt', v)));
      console.log('done file : ' + k);
  }
  })();
```

above code processes 34mb file 
I run it like

> node des.js 
>     Killed

I run in virtual box 512 mb ram Ubuntu server

I am new to javascript is the algorithm so bad, or is it something else. how can I improve it thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to simplify your code to see why it's failing? Without your data, it's hard to tell what's going wrong. It's clearly creating a lot of ever-growing arrays.

Comment: Oh my mistake file was actually 34 mb, I have split the file into 500kb chunks it worked fine, though still should it get killed? I guess this is an Ubuntu question how can I monitor performance and see the limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is failing because, as you seem to suspect, it's running out of memory.  I can't tell exactly what you're doing with `fieldMap`, but a quick script that splits 32mb of text on newlines and then splits each line at 5 chars takes 560mb on my mac, so your VM isn't going to be able to handle it.

You're going to have to read that file one line at a time, and write the output as it's generated.  The async methods in the `fs` module are a good place to start, but I think what you really want might be [node-lazy](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy).  Check out the `lines` method on `Lazy` to get started.

You might implement it something like this.

```
var fs = require('fs');

// we use modules lazy and temp, so you have 
// to run "npm install lazy temp" for this script
// to work.
var Lazy = require('lazy');
var tempfile = require('temp');

// Return a function that splits a line around a character
function lineSplitter(char){
  return function(string){
    // use string.toString() so we're ok if string happens to 
    // be a Buffer (lazy generates them, it seems)
    return string.toString().split(char);
  }
}

// Take a file, pass each line to lineHandler, and 
// call done after the entire file has been processed
function parseWholeFile(filename, lineHandler, done){
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
  Lazy(stream)
    .lines
    .map(lineSplitter('^'))
    .forEach(lineHandler)
    .join(done); 
}

function lineHandler(parts){
  // do something to parts...
  // we'll just append json to a file
  fs.appendFile('/tmp/out.json', JSON.stringify(parts),function(error){
    // ignore it for brevity
  });
}

// This is how you do a main function in node
if(require.main === module){
  // my file lives at /tmp/bigish, but you can pass yours 
  // as a command line argument
  // /tmp/bigish is a 32MB file with lines of around 1kb
  // consisting of 64 byte parts separated by '^' character 
  var filename = process.argv[2] || '/tmp/bigish';
  var started = new Date();

  parseWholeFile(filename, lineHandler, function(){
    var ended = new Date();
    console.log("took " + (ended - started) + "ms");
  });
}
```

Comment: fs.appendFile gives error ERROR: EMFILE OPEN , too many file descriptors I guess. Moved it to join callback problem solved. But the final log showing the time prints 'null', any idea why?

Comment: Haha, I didn't think  about the too many fds problem.  No idea why the time would print as null.